# How to not allow - (hyphens) in first char only?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to not allow `-` (hyphens) in first char only ?

http://jsfiddle.net/cewjsjrp/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Remove Special Characters from the Textbox - Coding cluster</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function deleteSpecialChar(txtName) {
            if (txtName.value != '' && txtName.value.match(/^[\w ]+$/) == null) 
            {
                txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/[\W]/g, '');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" >
    <div>
        <input id="txtName"  type="text" onkeyup="javascript:deleteSpecialChar(this)" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/^[\W]/, '');
                                       ^    ^
                                       |    |
                    replace by first char   |
                                            |
                                      global flag removed
```

And to replace `--` anywhere in text add after code above this line:

```
txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/\-+/g, '-');
                                         ^
                                         |
                                    means 1 or more occurrences
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cewjsjrp/3/).

Comment: and i want to not allow `--` it's meant i allow `-a-` or `-222-`

but not allow `--`

Comment: 1. not allow first char with `-` this is ok



2. not allow fill with `--` every position

Comment: i not good in English langues, could you please see this page 

(in find domain input)

https://register.hostgator.com/

my idea like this.

Comment: in your fiddle when i fill eg: `oi-------------------` it's will show 

`oi-----` but in register.hostgator.com show only `oi-`